# Transit at Munich Airport

Tags: transit, luggage, germany

I am planning to buy a single ticket for Doha to Cologne via munich. my flight plan is

Doha - Munich on Qatar Airways

Munich - Cologne on airberlin

Qatar Airways and airberlin have a codeshare agreement on the later flight.

I have a three and a half hour transit, which I think is enough for any immigration and other formalities. My questions are

- Would I need to go through immigration at Munich or at Cologne ( since I'm coming on a study visa from a non-Schengen)
- Would I remain airside at the Munich airport?
- would I need to claim my luggage, and check-in as a new passenger or not? (I'm booking both these flights on a single ticket?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under normal circumstances you will

- remain airside
- have the baggage checked through to Cologne
- go through immigration at Munich
- have plenty of time left in Munich
- go through customs at Cologne